# How to view files in laravel 5.7 (use multiple file upload code) and how to edit them

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

I am upload multiple file in laravel 5.7 files are uploaded in database but i am enable to view on admin panel and how to edit these files .How to display these images on admin panel and how to edit these files . Here is my code given below:

This is my controller to upload file

```
public function addProduct(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->isMethod('get'))
        { 
          return view('admin.product.add-product');
        }
        if($request->isMethod('post'))
        {    

            $this->validate($request,[
                'product_name'  => 'required|max:40',
                'price'         => 'required',
                'product_type'  => 'required', 
                'quantity'  => 'required',
                'description'  => 'required',
                'image' => 'required',
                'image.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg'

            ]);

           $product = new Product();
           $product->product_name = $request->product_name;
           $product->price = $request->price;
           $product->product_type = $request->product_type;
           $product->quantity = $request->quantity;
           $product->description = $request->description;

           //image upoad code
            //return $request->all();
          if($request->hasfile('image'))

        {
            // return $request->image;
               foreach($request->file('image') as $images)
            {

                     //var_dump($images);
                    $name=$images->getClientOriginalName();
                    $images->move(public_path().'/images/', $name);  
                    $data[] = $name;  
            }
        }


           $product->image=json_encode($data);
           $product->save();

           return redirect('admin/product-management'); 
        }
    }
```

Code to view file on admin panel is:

```
@foreach ($product as $products)
    @php $images = json_decode($product->image,true);
    @endphp

    @if(is_array($images) && !empty($images))
        @foreach ($images as $image)
            <img src="{{ url('public/images/'.$images) }}"/>
        @endforeach
    @endif
@endforeach
```

i upload files to public/images folder. How to edit and display images on admin panel.

in database images are stored as 
["download.jpeg","download.png","download (2).jpeg"]

Comment: What do you mean by _"edit"_ the images? You should also include what happens when you run your admin view. Btw, shouldn't it be `@foreach ($products as $product)`? (I've flipped the variables)

Comment: images are definitely saving correctly because she use  json_encode after `if` statement

Comment: yes images are uploaded

Comment: also from this line <img src="{{ url('public/images/'.$images) }}"/> changes from $images to $image . i do this doesnot make any change

Comment: yes thx for the help

Comment: sir foreach loop repeat one image three times how to solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
@php $images = json_decode($product->image,true);
@endphp

@if(is_array($images) && !empty($images))
    @foreach ($images as $image)
        <img src="{{ asset('images/'.$image) }}"/>
    @endforeach
@endif
@endforeach
```

Here i removed url function and use asset function , asset make complete url for public directory

Comment: Why should the OP _"try this"_? What does it solve and how? A good answer includes an _explanation_, not just a code dump.

Comment: asset function make complete url

Comment: You should edit your answer to include the explanation. The first foreach still looks wrong though. It should most likely be `@foreach ($products as $product)`.

Comment: You still don't have any explanation in your answer.

Comment: please wait , i am explaining it.

Answer (score 1):

just remove the public keyword from image path and check again

```
@foreach ($product as $products)
    @php $images = json_decode($product->image,true);
    @endphp

    @if(is_array($images) && !empty($images))
        @foreach ($images as $image)
            <img src="{{ url('images/'.$image) }}"/>
        @endforeach
    @endif
@endforeach
```

I also removed 's' from `{{ url('images/'.$image) }}`

Comment: The first foreach still looks wrong though. It should most likely be `@foreach ($products as $product)`.